# parse json-like structure/string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this variable:

```
var txt = { 
    'e3fe40': { 
        'name' : 'Menu2',
        'data': {
            'prompt_say' : 'Thank you for calling ',
            'keys[]' : ['1','2'],
            'choices[]' : [
                'start/e3fe40/d2d27',
                'start/e3fe40/77c197'
            ]...
```

While I can parse with no problems things such as `txt[position].data`.... , I cannot seem to be able to parse these two:

> `txt[position].data.keys` and `txt[position].data.choices`
>
> <sup>(last two entries from code above)</sup>

I tried with

```
txt[position].data.keys[1], 
txt[position].data.keys[],
txt[position].data.keys
```

etc.

None worked. I always get `"undefined"` value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt[position].data['keys[]']
```

The key `keys[]` is the name of the key.  You can't arbitrarily insert JSON-like strings in as a key name and expect it to parse.  This obviously assumes that the value of `position` is `e3fe40` or whatever it needs to be.

Comment: correct, position is "e3fe40" . So how would I go around and see that the "keys" key contains '1' and '2'?

Comment: The code I posted gets you the value of the `keys[]` element.  It's an array that contains two elements... the strings `1` and `2`.  What were you expecting?

Comment: Nothing, i was just super tired and read through the lines :) I saw what you were saying after reading it for the second time. Thanks!